# How To Scale and Center X Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to plot stem charts but depending on the data. These charts are being used in automated graph reports which the data isn't always consistent in range. Could vary from 24 to 96 in number of values. The graph would scale differently or move too far in a margin depending on the range.. 
I tried using tight_layout and autoscale but that does not produce the ideal results. 
Certain graphs have multiple subplots for comparison but they share the same x axis. There is also another ax for temperature.

How can I have the subplots x axis fixed so that all the values are within the border of the plot?

In the screen shot the initial tick value is 00:00 but it doesn't show and crops both ends.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8dfS.png)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
temperature_ax = ax.twinx()
(markers, stemlines, baseline) = plt.stem(kw, label='Demand', markerfmt='C0o') # bar chart

temperature_ax.plot(x_values_temperature, temperature, color=color, linewidth=2, label='Temperature', )
...
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3, top=0.7) 
fig.set_size_inches(8, 11)
ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to try using `figsize`. Since, you haven't provided the code I cannot help much but I am assuming you are using `matplotlib` in which case using the following line of code might help.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
```

You can change the value (14,8) which is (width,height), and play around with different numbers till you get the desired fit. You can read more about the function [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html).

Comment: My apologies. I updated my post to be a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Unfortunately setting the fig size doesn't resolve the issue, my solution is making the x values and xticks fixed so they are centered and aren't directly on the margin. Similar to how the y axis has a lift from the bottom margin, I would like that spacing around the entire subplots

Comment: Did you try ylim()?

Comment: Try `plt.ylim(bottom=0)`
You can try setting limits on the x axis and y axis. This often helps offset the plot.

Comment: It's not the yaxis I want changed but rather the  x axis. Neither ylim nor xlim does that though

Comment: Oh ok I saw your edit. You can also try setting xticks. Details [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html)

Comment: Also what do you mean by subplots? I can only see one figure here if you mean two plots on the same figure then `fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3, top=0.7)` won't help. Because this is two adjust the distance between two separate subplots.